# wordpressのLightiningの子テーマにてテキストや写真をページ中央に持ってくる方法について

Tags: wordpress

いつもお世話になっております。

現在wordpressでLightiningの子テーマにて
webページを作成しており、
固定ページのテキストや写真を画面の中央に配置したいのですが
なかなかできず悩んでいます。（写真を添付しましたのでご参照ください。）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

クラシックエディターを使っているのですが
中央配置にしても、テキストは中央になりますが
ブロック？全体が左によってしまいます。

クラシックエディターの中身はこのように書いているのですが
なにか勘違いしているせいかうまくいきません。

```
<p style="text-align: center;    
　　　　　　margin-left: auto;
    　　　 margin-right: auto;">
<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-54" src="http://yoko.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/marguerite-729510_1920-300x195.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="195" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;    
　　　　　　margin-left: auto;
    　　　 margin-right: auto;">
テスト</p>
```

テキストや写真をページ中央に持ってくるには
どうしたらいいでしょうか？

Comment: 画像をみる限り、サイドバーがなにも見えてないもののカラム自体は残ってい(あるいは2カラム用の設定になっている？)、メインコンテンツ領域がおそらく意図されているものとは異なっているのであるように見えます。Lightningの設定で1カラムにするのは https://lightning.nagoya/ja/archives/lightning-9-0-pro-4-0 などでできるはずですが……

Comment: ありがとうございます。カラムを１にしたら中央になりました！